# Filtering WSS SharePoint 2010 List via Dropdown

Tags: list, sharepoint, filter, wss

I am using WSS 2010 and need a filter drop down for one of my lists. I would really like a precompiled solution, because my Visual Studio does not support the project type for creating webparts, so I can't use any of the current solutions available. Essentially I am limited to editing the website by anything other than the designer or in page.

Comment: If you're limited to working through SharePoint Designer and the browser, consider leveraging the built-in Filter Web Part: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx

Comment: I figured out that the site base type didn't support filters and had to recreate the site to get the filter to appear. No clue why it's not available on all sites, since it could be used with any list... Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change site type to publishing or Business Intelligence Center. For some reason, it is not able to be enabled (even with enterprise package enabled) on blank sites.